# using SVG dom inside a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to use the [*SVG DOM*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html) to manipulate path points (for simplicity in this case). The problem is that the inside on a `<svg>` tag that lives inside a webpage as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>svg dom access</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg id="SVG">
        <path id="foo" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to access the svg DOM at all? I would like to run something along the line of:

```
//get svg dom somehow
var path = document.getElementById('foo');
var segments = path.normalizedPathSegList;

for (var i=0,len=segments.numberOfItems;i<len;++i){
    var pathSeg = segments.getItem(i);
    pathSeg.x = pathSeg.x + someFunction(pathSeg.x); 
}
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he2rucmy/) can be found here for experimentation.

**Edity**: I'm really looking to access to *SVG DOM* if possible. Otherwise i will just rewrite the d tag but id rather not parse the data,, but I will if I must

Comment: You can try using d3.js

Comment: @Zargold sure, i could. But i don't really want a library to do this i just want to do it with raw acess. I do understand that the state of svg sucks in current form... still not want a external library to do incredibly easy lifting of data

Comment: How about with CSS then if you just want to lift the items? ```
#foo { position: absolute; bottom: 40px;}``` or do the same with javascript style attribute see if that works? you can loop through each portion of the array if you have to have it be dynamic and add a style attribute see if that works? Just make sure the container has a position setting of some sort like position:relative or position:absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem in your fiddle is the `normalizedPathSegList`, which doesn't seem to be implemented consistently, but you can use `pathSegList`, it'll give the result you want.

```
var segments = path.pathSegList;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73ffn15k/

Comment: Thank you, `pathSegList` will do. The function would just have been easier if i would have had the data normalized but this is definitely better than any other alternative. So close.